# SonarQube LDAP 1.4 -> debug logging

Tags: logging, plugins, ldap, sonarqube

What is the preferred way to display the debug log level information from the latest SonarQube LDAP 1.4 plugin. I did not find the logging conf file.
Thanks.

Comment: btw, I use the latest Sonarqube 5.1.2 version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends which version of SonarQube you are running on:

- prior to SQ 5.1, there's a bug that prevents to have the DEBUG logs of the LDAP plugin. There's a ticket for this and we should provide a fix in the upcoming month: [LDAP-2](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/LDAP-2)
- starting with SQ 5.1, you just have to set `sonar.log.level=DEBUG` in the `conf/sonar.properties` file and you're done.

Comment: For some reason, even after restarting the service, this didn't help for me.  I deleted the old sonar.log file and then restarted the service, and that seemed to have worked.  I'm not sure why that would have been an issue.